# Diferenciar itensv

Tags: java

Tenho duas classes sendo cadastradas, a classe Refeicao e AlimentoRefeicao. Elas realizam vários cadastros ao mesmo tempo, mas não estou conseguindo diferenciar os itens para cada refeição. Eu seleciono a refeição e seus respectivos alimentos ao selecionar uma nova refeição e outros alimentos, quando realizo o cadastro os dados estão ficando incoerentes, pois ele cadastra todos os alimentos dentro de uma mesma refeição e na refeição seguinte ele cadastra os mesmos itens.

```
String diasRefeicao[] = request.getParameterValues("diarefeicao");
String idTipoRefeicao[] = request.getParameterValues("idtiporefeicao");

Cardapio cardapio = new Cardapio();
cardapio.setIdCardapio(idCardapio);

String alimentos[] = request.getParameterValues("idalimento");
String quantidades[] = request.getParameterValues("quantidadealimentorefeicao");
String medidaalimento[] = request.getParameterValues("tipomedidaalimentorefeicao");

Integer idRefeicao = null;


try {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < idTipoRefeicao.length; ii++){
        TipoRefeicao tipoRefeicao = new TipoRefeicao();
        tipoRefeicao.setIdTipoRefeicao(Integer.parseInt(idTipoRefeicao[ii]));

        Refeicao refeicao = new Refeicao();
        refeicao.setDiaRefeicao(diasRefeicao[ii].toUpperCase().trim());
        refeicao.setStatusRefeicao("A");
        refeicao.setSincronizaRefeicao(1);
        refeicao.setTipoRefeicao(tipoRefeicao);
        refeicao.setCardapio(cardapio);

        RefeicaoDAOImpl daorefeicao = new RefeicaoDAOImpl();
        idRefeicao = daorefeicao.cadastrar(refeicao);

        if (idRefeicao != null) {
            refeicao.setIdRefeicao(idRefeicao);
            for (int i = 0; i < alimentos.length; i++) {
                AlimentoRefeicao alimentoRefeicao = new AlimentoRefeicao();
                Alimento alimento = new Alimento();

                alimento.setIdAlimento(Integer.parseInt(alimentos[i]));
                alimentoRefeicao.setAlimento(alimento);
                alimentoRefeicao.setRefeicao(refeicao);
                alimentoRefeicao.setTipoMedidaAlimentoRefeicao(medidaalimento[i]);
                alimentoRefeicao.setQuantidadeAlimentoRefeicao(Double.parseDouble(quantidades[i]));
                alimentoRefeicao.setSincronizaAlimentoRefeicao(1);
                try{
                    GenericDAO dao = new AlimentoRefeicaoDAOImpl();
                if (dao.cadastrar(alimentoRefeicao)) {
                    mensagem = "Cadastrado com sucessso ";
                } else {
                    mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar itens da refeição";
                }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Erro ao cadastrar itens da refeição" + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Uma refeição não esta referenciada a um comilão? :) Senão a que/quem ela está referenciada?

Comment: A refeição está ligada ao cardápio na qual tem ligação com o paciente

Comment: Eu estava com um problema no outro tópico ninguém me ajudou. Ai consegui resolver com a ajuda de outro forum, alterei a questão pois não tinha nenhuma resposta. Vieram e falaram q eu não podia fazer isso. Então criei outro tópico. Mas OK espero o outro forum me responder. Vlw

Comment: Leticia você distorceu o que disse [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108212/cadastro-duplicado#comment223958_108212). Eu apenas te alertei sobre essa prática, que não era recomendada, mas também ressaltei que, como a pergunta ainda não tinha respostas, mesmo tendo comentarios, não teria grandes problemas. Se esta pergunta é de outro problema, não será fechada como duplicata, mas seria interessante você postar a solução que achou da outra como resposta la, pra mostrar que são problemas distintos.